# Script within a jQueryUI modal dialog box only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table that, when any row is clicked, launches a jQueryUI modal dialog box to allow users to edit that record. I use the following script which seems to work, successfully loading the relevant record's details in using AJAX:

```
$("#datatbl tr").bind('click', function() {        
        var url = 'item_edit.asp?id='+$(this).attr("data-myid");
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:hidden" title="Record details:"></div>').appendTo('body');
        // load remote content
        dialog.load(
            url, 
            {},
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({         
                    height: 440,
                    width: 550,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Update this record": function() {
                         $('#editform').submit();
                            },
                        Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
        });
        dialog.dialog('open');
            }
        );
        //prevent the browser to follow the link
        return false;
});
```

It works ok the first time I click on a record, but if I click cancel and try to edit another record, the dialog box does appear (with the correct record details) however, no scripts within the dialog box work - eg: there's a jqueryUI datepicker input and some validation.

There are no javascript errors and, from my limited understanding of FireBug, I can't spot anything going wrong so I would appreciate some advice how to proceed, thanks!

***EDIT: Argh! Sometimes, it takes something like typing it out here to spot the obvious. I just realised that the DIV created for the dialog box doesn't get destroyed when the box closes. I've added a line to do this and it now works. Thanks for listening. :)***

For future reference, I added an ID to the DIV created in 'var dialog' and removed it in the Cancel function:

```
Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        $('#dialogbox').remove();
                        }
```

I'd still appreciate if anybody suggests a better way to handle this behaviour.

Comment: you should add your edit to an answer and accept the answer.

Comment: I tried, but need to wait 8 hours. I'll do it then, but in the meantime I'll edit the original post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it: the DIV created for the dialog box doesn't get destroyed when the box closes.

I added an ID to the DIV created in 'var dialog' and removed the DIV in the Cancel function:

```
Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        $('#dialogbox').remove();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dialog at one time only, not on every load of its content, just set the autoOpen to false.

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="content" style="display:hidden" title="Record details:"></div>
</div>

$('#dialog').dialog({
    height: 440,
    width: 550,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Update this record": function() {
            $('#editform').submit();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
$("#datatbl tr").bind('click', function() {        
    var url = 'item_edit.asp?id='+$(this).attr("data-myid");
    // load remote content
    $('#content').load(url);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
}};
```

Comment: The autoOpen <i>is</i> set to false. Opening the dialog wasn't the problem, it was the fact that the box didn't work the same if opened, closed then opened again. (see above). Thanks for reply